# Symfony form not working properly if a field is empty or not exists

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony5

To edit the entity training, I use the TrainingFormType like this:

```
public function editTraining(Training $training) {
    $form = $this->createForm(TrainingFormType::class, $training);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());
```

The form has a field title:

```
->add('title', TextType::class, [
      'constraints' => [
          new NotBlank(),
          new Length(null, null, 50)
]])
```

If I pass in the request an empty value into the field title `"title" : ""`, I get an error 500:

"Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "title".". I expected here an error from the form, not the InvalidArgumentException

When using the same form for creating of a new training, everything works fine, a validation error is generated, as expected:

```
"title": {
          "errors": [
            "This value should not be blank."
          ]
},
```

It's how I use the form when creating a new training:

```
$training = new Training();
$form = $this->createForm(TrainingFormType::class, $training);
$form->submit($request->request->all());
```

How to solve this problem? I thought, I can resolve it using an so called IgnoreNonSubmittedFieldListener, but on this way it also doesn't work. I get the same error.

Comment: I solved the problem by adding `'empty_data' => ''` to the field. It works for me, but is it a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to set a sensible default in the `Training` entity for that field:

```
// in Training.php

// ORM mapping omitted:
private string _title = '';
```

Then when a new entity is created it will have that value.